# How to change the interpolation easing of multiple keyframes at once?

Tags: animation, interface, workflow, keyframes, graph-editor

[image]

The easing direction setting in the image above only affects the active keyframe, and when right clicked on the *copy to selected* operator is grayed out.

Is python the only way to set this on all selected keyframes at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> or choose from the menu Key -> Easing Type.

This will affect all selected points. But i don't think it is possible yet to set the easing parameters simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I wanted :) I'm not sure I get your last sentence though.. What do you mean by "not possible"? Doesn't Ctrl+E do it?

Comment: @gandalf3 different easing types, have different parameters you can adjust in the "F-Curve" Panel. I am also wondering if nowadays there is a smarter way to manipulate these for multiple keys at once. e.g. trying to get the same easing for all axes of my scale keyframes, but I have to manually type the values for each axis